# Environment variables issue - commands stop working in cmd prompt

Tags: windows, environment-variables, command-prompt

After installing one of our application, none of the commands work in command prompt. It says 'command is not recognized as an internal or external command'. After opening the environment variables -> Path -> Do nothing Just say Ok, then the commands start working. This seems to be an interesting issue and came across a blog on the same http://aricsblog.blogspot.in/2007/02/command-paths-not-working-and.html . But just wondering what could be the root cause for this issue? And can someone explain on caching of environment variables?

Comment: "Command Prompt not working" is a very poor title. You clearly understand that your problem has to do with environment variables. Why not ask a more specific question like "Environment variables not persisting" or whatever it is you really want to know.

Comment: Yes Jonathon changed title